# Get the length of an element on nested list

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a list (of lists) that came from JSON (`jsonlite`) like this one (`dput` below)

```
{
    "1":["123", "131", "342"],
    "2":["123", "131"],
    "3":["123", "131", "352"],
    "4":["31", "352"],
    "5":["153", "131"],
    "6":["153", "131", "382"]
}

structure(list(`1` = c("123", "131", "342"), `2` = c("123", "131" ), `3` = c("123", "131", "352"), `4` = c("31", "352"), `5` = c("153", "131"), `6` = c("153", "131", "382")), .Names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

Then, I'm trying to convert it to a data frame with the key and the length of the nested list, like

```
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6
1  1  2  3  4  5  6
2  3  2  3  2  2  3
```

with that code:

```
 a = (read_file("ghist.json") %>% fromJSON)$hist # Reads my list from a JSON file
 dates = data.frame() #Creates an empty data frame

 #Iterate my list element by element
 for(i in 1:length(a)){
   dates[1, i] = strtoi(names(a)[i]) #Appends to my data frame on the first row, line 'i' the key from my list (index 'i'), as Integer
   dates[2, i] = length(a[i]) #Here is my problem, it returns '1', not the real length of my list (index 'i')
 }
 print(dates) #Just debug
```

With the code above I'm getting

```
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6
1  1  2  3  4  5  6
2  1  1  1  1  1  1
```

**Note:** I know the numbers on key are just crescent numbers, but it will become dates in ms

Comment: Can you `dput` the list created by `jsonlite`? Is it putting keys as element names and values as vectors?

Comment: dput here: ``structure(list(`1` = c("123", "131", "342"), `2` = c("123", "131"
), `3` = c("123", "131", "352"), `4` = c("31", "352"), `5` = c("153", 
"131"), `6` = c("153", "131", "382")), .Names = c("1", "2", "3", 
"4", "5", "6"))
``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use the built in `lengths` function to construct your data frame. This gives you the length of list elements, which is exactly what you want.

```r
a <- structure(list(`1` = c("123", "131", "342"), `2` = c("123", "131"), `3` = c("123", "131", "352"), `4` = c("31", "352"), `5` = c("153", "131"), `6` = c("153", "131", "382")), .Names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))

dates <-  data.frame(
  matrix(
    data = c(names(a), lengths(a)),
    ncol = length(a),
    byrow = TRUE
    )
  )
dates
#>   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6
#> 1  1  2  3  4  5  6
#> 2  3  2  3  2  2  3
```

The bug in your code is very minor, thought I wouldn't recommend this approach. It's that you need `length(a[[i]])`. I suggest you [look at some resources on subsetting in R](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/vectors.html#subsetting-1), but to illustrate compare the two at the bottom. `a[1]` returns a list containing the desired element, `a[[1]]` returns the actual element. The length of `a[1]` is 1.

```r
dates = data.frame()
for(i in 1:length(a)){
  dates[1, i] = strtoi(names(a)[i]) 
  dates[2, i] = length(a[[i]]) # changed here
}
dates
#>   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6
#> 1  1  2  3  4  5  6
#> 2  3  2  3  2  2  3

a[1]
#> $`1`
#> [1] "123" "131" "342"
a[[1]]
#> [1] "123" "131" "342"
```

Created on 2018-06-26 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot. Sadly I can't upvote your answer

Comment: Glad it was useful! If it helped you can accept it as the answer.

Comment: Sorry I forgot it :c

Answer (score -2):

Try nrow(a[i]) instead of length(a[i]) in your loop.